# FindFormula can't deal with the population data from Wolfram server

Tags: bugs, fitting

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and fixed in 10.3**

---

In the documentation of `FindFormula`, the first application of it is to predict the population of Poland.

```
data = EntityValue[Entity["Country", "Poland"], 
EntityProperty["Country", 
"Population", {"Date" -> 
Interval[{DateObject[{1950}], DateObject[{2015}]}]}]]
fit = FindFormula[data, x]
```

However, when I tried to run the code, it did not work and gave the following error:

> FindFormula::wrgfmt: Argument {{QuantityMagnitude[Sun 1 Jan 1950 00:00:00GMT+8.],2.4824*10^7},{QuantityMagnitude[Mon 1 Jan 1951 00:00:00GMT+8.],2.52623*10^7},<<47>>,{QuantityMagnitude[Fri 1 Jan 1999 00:00:00GMT+8.],3.8336*10^7},<<16>>} at position 1 does not have the right format. Data should be a numerical array of depth less or equal than 2. >>

It seems that `QuantityMagnitude` cannot deal with that `DateObject`, but `AbsoluteTime` will do the job. My idea to fix this is to change some Mathematica code in `FindFormula`. I tried `Information[FindFormula]`, but it returned a lot of private packages, and I don't know how to track down then. Is there any workaround to get `FindFormula` to work with these population data?

Comment: Have you tried converting the dates into something like `AbsoluteTime[]` instead and fitting with that?

Comment: Yes, I noticed this too.  The documentation says `FindFormula` is experimental.  I guess that means "beta", and the docs are out of sync with the development.  Many of the other `FindFormula` documentation examples don't give the same output that's shown in the documentation.

Comment: You might try `fit = FindFormula[data // Normal, x]`. I can't test this, I don't have V10.2

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for your advice, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Szabolcs The differences when evaluating the examples are because `FindFormula` uses stochastic algorithms with randomized seeds. There is a `"RandomSeed"` option that should make the function give the same answers always, but it's currently not working properly.

Comment: As to the question posed: This is a bug in `FindFormula` in 10.2 which we are aware of.

Comment: @StefanR You're right, it seems I was just unlucky the first time I tried it, and I got a really bad fit.  That doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 5):

With J. M.'s idea, there is a temporary workaround to convert population data to lists and make it work with `FindFormula`. Assume `data` has been set like in the question.

```
data2 = Transpose[{(AbsoluteTime /@ 
      List /@ Range[First@#[[1]], First@#[[2]], 
        First@#[[3]]]) &[#[[2]]], #[[1]]}] &[
Flatten[data[[2]][[1 ;; 2]], 1]];
FindFormula[data2, x]
```

[image: piecewise function]

For some unknown reasons, this result is not the same as that in the doc.
And the plot in the doc will be modified to this

```
ListPlot[MapAt[QuantityMagnitude, #, 2] & /@ data2]
```

[image: the plot]